# Nginx + passenger segmentation fault error

Tags: ruby, nginx, ruby-1.9.3

I'm experiencing a segmentation fault error on an nginx server handling a rails 3.2 application.

I tried to update all the application gems, tried to update nginx to the latest version but without luck...

Nginx is at version 1.2.4 with passenger version 3.0.18.
Ruby version: 1.9.3-p362

This is the error log: http://pastebin.com/z0GbNC9m

Ask any more info you could need!

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Active record doesn't use any native extensions by itself, so it's likely that this is a bug in ruby. I'd upgrade to the most recent patch version of ruby (currently `1.9.3-p429`) and see whether that fixes it. Otherwise you might like to report it as a bug.

Comment: I've updated to ruby 1.9.3-p429 and the problem has been solved :)

thanks!